# Recover LOST password on Intel Edison

Tags: linux, arduino

I've previously installed Yocto Linux Image on my edison and configured with login and pw.

I have misplaced the pw, hwoever all the instructions I've read for re flashing the device require a login and pw.
This seems to be a chicken and egg problem

If the ONLY solution is to reflash the Edison,
https://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-23193
https://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-23192

and you need your login -pw credentials first to do so, exactly how do you recover them?

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this with I've never done anything with, read up on or have much of a clue as to what Yocto is.

Can you mount the file-system and modify /etc/shadow?  If so you should be able to find the user name and delete everything in between the first and second colon ':'.  This should effectively blank your users password.

Example:

```
test:$6$LwfKyq6e$jGvH81jbF3IgchBbA5Ea968nRpi4ODw24pO37bes8QjZYsdwO49v3KzWf106b.An7wcrxTa8qbVcccgzED/0y0:16456:0:99999:7:::
```

to

```
test::16456:0:99999:7:::
```